# link texlive to github repository

Tags: texlive, git, repositories

I have a package of commands `commands.sty` on github. Is there a way that I can point TexLive to this github repository so that I can use `\includepackage{commands}` in any local document?

So far, I've tried going into `Configure > Manage Repositories > My Repositories` and adding the `https://github.com/myuser/commands.git` url.

Comment: you can't point it at github  (or any site, latex has no http access built in) but assuming you have a local clone checked out you can have that directory in your texinputs

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: Do you mean that I can add the path of the local clone to the `Configure > Manage Repositories > My Repositories`?

Comment: I have no idea what application that configure menu refers to sorry, no as I say latex has no idea about http (it predates the web) if your local clone is checked out as `~/my repositoreies/commands` then set the environment variable TEXINPUTS to ` `~/my repositoreies/commands//:` so tex looks there before looking in the standard search tree